# Spring Boot .war context path for Undertow and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot application which I will deploy as a .war file in existing Tomcat and Undertow(Wildfly) containers. How can I configure the context path from within the application?

I know I can use the .war name directly, but I dont want to do that since the .war name contains version information etc.

Comment: Are you using Undertow as a part of the wildfly server? i.e. deploying the webapp to both tomcat and wildfly?

Comment: Yes undertow is basically a wildfly server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Tomcat configuration docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)
Defining a context:

> Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> - In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application    files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML
>     attribute) this may be    copied to
>     $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to
>     application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.
> - ...

Also note:

> If you want to deploy a WAR file or a directory using a context path
>   that is not related to the base file name then one of the following
>   options must be used to prevent double-deployment:
>
> - Disable autoDeploy and deployOnStartup and define all Contexts in    server.xml
> - Locate the WAR and/or directory outside of the Host's    appBase and use a context.xml file with a docBase attribute to define    it.

Also this is along the lines of what you are looking for [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7276989/4807777)

For undertow, if it's used as a web server in the wildfly AS try it with  a jboss-web.xml like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28475123/4807777

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the by adding a /WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml file in the application that you deploy:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
   <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>`

As noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28475123/912829