# How to configure Context with path and location Wildfly 10

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly-10

Hi i was using one configuration in server.xml in jboss-4.2.3

```
 <Context  docBase="/data/rohit/files/upload/evaluecdmdocument" path="/images" />
```

Now i am switching to wildfly 10, and not able to find any way how can i achieve the same in wildfly.

It would be great is someone can help me.

Comment: What does docBase mean?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470872/how-to-define-context-path-in-wildfly?rq=1