# Using "/" as default project root on Jboss Wildfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, ear

I have a wildfly-14.0.1.Final server and a project (`foodHosting`) with a deployable ear module named `foodHosting-ear` and a web war module named `fooHosting-web`. After the deploy to reach my index.xhtml I have to write `localhost:8080/foodHosting-web/` to my browser. Is there any solution to write only `localhost:8080` and show my application? Like `localhost:8080/index.xhtml`?

Comment: Have a look at that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470872/how-to-define-context-path-in-wildfly)

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename the `fooHosting-web.war` to `ROOT.war`

Edit: It's not needed to rename the .war inside your .ear, you have to change the context-root as the answer @wirnse said in the comment, but instead of /WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml check your /META-INF/application.xml and empty the context-root tag: `<context-root></context-root>`