# how to change the root url in wildfly

Tags: url, wildfly

I use wildfly for deployment of an application but I want to change URL of :9081/Portal/login to :9081/
Here is file web.xml :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by combining your `web.xml` and answer to this question on StackOverflow: [How to define Context Path in Wildfly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470872/how-to-define-context-path-in-wildfly)

So, to sum it up:

1. Define `<context-root>` of your app as described in the linked question
2. Define a `<welcome-file>` as you are suggesting, writing `<welcome-file>/jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>` should do

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is possible to use this approach to change the deployed app port, instead of 8080? For example in Spring, for application.properties, server.port=8093 does the trick.