# How to configure or customize REALM Metadata endpoints in Keycloak for SAML2.0

Tags: docker, keycloak, saml, saml-2.0

**Context:**

I have a keycloak inside a docker, I understand that there is a "proxy reverse" doing something like transforming this url for example: "http://example.com" into "http://171.20.2.97:8082" (this is the actual place where the Keycloak is "deployed" or "up"). It is just an example, my clients when they need to consume an endpoint from one microservice of mine do not use numbers, they use example.com.

so in the **Keycloak** when you want to see the metadata of the realm for SAML2.0 you can do it by following this link which is in the REALM settings section:
https://example.com/auth/realms/REALM-NAME/protocol/saml/descriptor

as you can see I am using "example.com" not "171.20.2.97:8082" to access the metadata link.

**The problem** is that inside the METADATA, the endpoints for SingleSignOnService, SingleLogoutService, etc. Are all configured to be "http://171.20.2.97:8082/auth/realms/REALM-NAME/protocol/saml" (notice it is using the numbers and not example.com) and this causes that when the clients that want to use SAML.

Send inside their SAML REQUEST "Destination" attribute like so: "http://example.com/auth/realms/REALM-NAME/protocol/saml" and this causes an invalid request error, with reason invalid_destination, because the request attribute Destination was expected to be:
"http://171.20.2.97:8082/auth/realms/REALM-NAME/protocol/saml" like is inside the Metadata.

**So my question is**, how can I edit the metadata to change the endpoints numbers to example.com or if that is not possible, how can I make example.com get translated to 171.20.2.97:8082 inside my keycloak server? Or if you know another way to solve/figure out this it is very welcome

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a BEAST after finding out how to achieve what I needed after like 3 weeks of searching about keycloak and SAML (I overcame many obstacles this was the lastone), finally **I managed to fix this by using the "Frontend URL" setting in my REALM settings**, there I can put anything I want so that it changes "http://171.20.2.97:8082/auth/" (inside the metadata urls) for whatever I configure there, so for example if I set **Frontend URL** to:

https://example.com/auth/

now all my metadata endpoints will be like so:

https://example.com/auth/realms/REALM-NAME/protocol/saml

instead of:

http://171.20.2.97:8082/auth/realms/REALM-NAME/protocol/saml

now my client is being able to properly login with SAML2 using keycloak.

how did I manage to find out this? Well there is not much info so this was what gave me the hint: [Keycloak behind nginx reverse proxy: SAML Integration invalid_destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210683/keycloak-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-saml-integration-invalid-destination)

The person asking said that he configured frontend-url, and I wanted to give a try to that, and after checking if that changed metadata urls, surprise it did =)